# Can anyone read this network diagram?

Tags: network-access

Can anyone read this network diagram?

I understand what a VLAN is. The information provided for the diagram is listed below.

"To demonstrate a real-world model of how you might use VLANs, I created a fictional zoned-network. In Figure 5-17, I isolated incoming Internet traffic and created internal data center security zones."

[image]

Comment: At this resolution, it's not readable for sure (although that probably was not what you wanted to ask)

Comment: Typically this isn't the place to ask questions from your school or coursework.

Also, the image is far too small in order to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the only question you ask: I can read most of it.

```
Externally Facing Security Zones
Data Center
Public Access
SSL VPN
VPN Concentrator
Edge switch
Private DB vlan
L2 Aggregation
IPS on Trunk
Core L3 Switch
email
Application Servers
Corporate Office
```

And the links are labeled with `vlan <number>` where the number differs per color.
Unfortunately the text in the green box is too small to read at this resolution.

Now the more interesting question would be: what does the author mean with "isolated" and "security zones". It looks like all vlans are connected to the core L3 switch, so if that switch routes between all these vlans then there is only isolation at L2 and so this use of vlans does not offer any security at all. If the L3 switch does not route between all vlans, then the non-routed vlans are indeed isolated but then they also don't have connectivity.
The only way this diagram would make sense (talking about security) is if the L3 Switch would be replaced with a firewall IMHO.
The Core L3 switch could be e.g. a Cisco 6500 with an ASA module but then I would expect it to be labeled as `core switch with firewall module` to make that clear.